# can not create a table with a headers row and add dynamic data to the headers and the data cells in ckeditor 5 and angular 9

Tags: angular, execute, ckeditor5

I want to create a table in Ckeditor 5 that must contain a header row and a data row. I have tried editor.execute to create a table with a header row and it was ok, but I don't know how to fill the header and data cells with my data programmatically.

```
editor.execute('insertTable', {rows: 2, columns: 4});
editor.execute('setTableRowHeader');
```

I also tried TableUtils plugin, I could create a table and fill it with my data, but I don't know how to make my first row as the header with this method.

```
const tableUtils = this.editor.plugins.get('TableUtils');
this.editor.model.change(writer => {
const table = tableUtils.createTable(writer, 2, result.length);

result.forEach((column, index) => {
        writer.insertText(`${column.Name}`, {bold: true}, 
        table.getChild(0).getChild(index).getChild(0), 0);
        writer.insertText(`{Tag.Embed.${column.Name}}`, 
        table.getChild(1).getChild(index).getChild(0), 0);
  });
  this.editor.model.insertContent(table);
});
```

Is there any solution to fix each of the above ways I have tried?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer thanks to CKEditor support guys.

```
const model = editor.model;

model.change( writer => {
// Create a table.
const table = tableUtils.createTable( writer, 2, 2 );
// Set it's "headingRows" attribute to 1.
writer.setAttribute( 'headingRows', 1, table );

// To simplify we'll take the first (only) data row.
const dataRow = table.getChild( 1 );

for ( const tableCell of dataRow.getChildren() ) {
    // Each created table cell have an empty paragraph as a child.
    const paragraph = tableCell.getChild( 0 );

    // Crete a content to insert - here just "foo" text.
    const text = writer.createText( 'foo' );

    // Insert text to a paragraph.
    const insertPosition = writer.createPositionAt( paragraph, 0 );
    writer.insert( text, insertPosition );
}

// Use model.insertContent() to insert a created content.
// It will insert table at a current document selection position.
model.insertContent( table );
} );
```